# OpenGl & CImg in C++

Tags: c++, opengl, glut, cimg

I am working to develop a basic 2D game using OpenGl. I have developed the basic game play & all that stuff but now i want to add a background image to my game window. I am using `glutCreateWindow()` to make my game window and calling the game display function named as `gameWindow()` all of my game 2d drawings are done here using OpenGl functions. Now i want to read an image from the same directory as my source code files and call it in the `gameWindow()` somehow and draw the background image. I have heard about the Cimg library but after looking at its docs it seems quite confusing as its docs focus mainly on image editing.

Is there a basic function which i can use to get desired result. I have heard about `glTextImage2D()` but it requires the image to be stored in 2D array right? So then how can i store my image (jpg/png) in 2D array and pass it to above function in order to get background image.

P.S. my glut window size is 840 x 900

Comment: If you are familiar with authoring OpenGL shaders, then you could simply create a RenderTarget with a texture and render that texture as a screen background before any other draw calls are made

Comment: I am not familiar with them, i just know how to draw basic 2D stuff on a window using opengl.

Comment: CImg will help you read the jpeg into a buffer.